# where condition not supporting more than 1 condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

The below code I want to use  more than one condition but it is not supporting it is taking only one condition  only `p.score<=35` it is only displaying all records but `p.score<=50` this condition applicable record is not dispying how can I resolve this issue.

```
cs=(from e in db.Students
  join p in db.Marks
  on e.S_ID equals p.S_ID
  join t in db.Details
  on p.School_ID equals t.School_ID
  where  p.Score<=35 && p.Score <=50
  select new MyModel
  {
      S_Name = e.S_Name,
      Score = (int)p.Score,
      Status = p.Status,
      Address_City = t.Address_City,
      Email_ID = t.Email_ID,
      Accomplishments = t.Accomplishments
  }).ToList();
```

Comment: The title of the question is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a list of marks `[15, 30, 35, 45, 50]`

Now as per the condition which you have applied in your code,
`where  p.Score<=35 && p.Score <=50`

you will get `[15,30,35]` because these elements satisfy both conditions (`<=35` && `<=50`)

you will not get `[45,50]` as these satisfy only one condition (`<=50`)

Since you have applied `&&` clause in between both conditions, the marks need to pass both conditions in order to be displayed. Passing only one condition is not enough.

Therefore, you need to change your `where` clause.

1. If you want to display all those marks which are less than or equal to 50, you need to write `where  p.Score <=50`
2. If you want to display only those marks which are less than or equal to 50 but greater than or equal to 35, you need to write `where  p.Score>=35 && p.Score <=50`

Answer (score 0):

```
p.Score<=35 && p.Score <=50
```

Is the same as simply `p.Score<=35`.

I assume you actually want

```
p.Score >= 35 && p.Score <= 50
```

i.e. score between 35 and 50?

Comment: Thanks but,I want to display in between score 35 and 50  simultaneously

Comment: Then you have a typo in your condition: use "p.Score>=35" instead of "p.Score<=35".

Comment: I changed but again getting same issue

Comment: What issue? 

You have "p.Score<=35 && p.Score <=50". This is the same as "p.Score<=35" (less than 35 AND less than 50 is same as less than 35). 

If you want between 35 and 50 (e.g. 38, 40, 49... but not 51 or 21...), you must put "p.Score >= 35 && p.Score <= 50". What unwanted results are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Change p.Score<=35 && p.Score <=50  to (p.Score>=35 && p.Score <=50).

```
cs=(from e in db.Students
join p in db.Marks
on e.S_ID equals p.S_ID
join t in db.Details
on p.School_ID equals t.School_ID
where  (p.Score>=35 && p.Score <=50)
select new MyModel
{
  S_Name = e.S_Name,
  Score = (int)p.Score,
  Status = p.Status,
  Address_City = t.Address_City,
  Email_ID = t.Email_ID,
  Accomplishments = t.Accomplishments
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Please share your data if not problem for you. I think there's an error in your data